# How do I move all the files from a folder (and subfolders) using the command line in Android 7.1+?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, 8.0-oreo

I tried using this command:

```
find /src/dir -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered -t /dst/dir {} +
```

[sourced from here](https://superuser.com/a/658078/264738), but error messages suggest `find` requires root on Android. Any other ideas as to how to accomplish this? I want only the files in the destination folder (i.e. without the directory structure, all files in one directory) while maintaining the source directory structure. I've tried Termux, Terminal Emulator, and Tasker so far, without success.

Comment: How are you running these commands? `adb shell` or some third-party terminal app?

Comment: `cp -a /src/dir /dst/dir`? Guess you want to keep the directory structure, right?

Comment: @TimothyLanger I've tried Termux, Terminal Emulator, and Tasker so far.

Comment: @Izzy No, I don't. I just want the files only in the destination folder while maintaining the source directory structure.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear to me (the command used could have been wrong ;) I've integrated that with your question, feel free to [edit] again if it doesn't fully fit. Strange though that your `find` claims to require root: I've checked on two devices (LP, MM) and it doesn't. Could you please specify device and Android version? Worth a try: `busybox find`. If there's no busybox, try `toybox`. Some variant is running on every device I've seen.

Comment: Here's the error I get trying toybox: 08.23.36/E Run Shell:  -> 
08.23.36/E Run Shell:  -> 
08.23.36/E Run Shell:  -> 
08.23.36/Shell runBackground toybox find /sdcard/Pictures -type f -exec mv /sdcard/Sync {} + root: false timeout: -1
08.23.36/Shell start process-thread ID 65322
08.23.36/E add wait type Shell1 time 2147483647
08.23.36/E add wait type Shell1 done
08.23.36/E add wait task
08.23.36/E Error: 1

Comment: Here's the Tasker error I get using busybox: 08.27.47/E Run Shell:  -> 
08.27.47/E Run Shell:  -> 
08.27.47/E Run Shell:  -> 
08.27.47/Shell runBackground busybox find /sdcard/Pictures -type f -exec mv /sdcard/Sync {} + root: false timeout: -1
08.27.47/Shell start process-thread ID 65335
08.27.47/E add wait type Shell1 time 2147483647
08.27.47/E add wait type Shell1 done
08.27.47/E add wait task
08.27.47/E Error: 127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some head-bashing I've realised there's a Linux-specific (Android being based on Linux) mistake being made here - when you type `/src/dir` the initial `/` implies that you're looking in the filesystem root, mounted at `/`. In this case, however, you're probably referring to the current directory, which will likely be in `/sdcard/` since you are not rooted. Simply omit the first slash and you're good to go (personally tested).

```
find src/dir -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered -t dst/dir {} +
```

If you find still can't perform the function (especially due to an error such as `unrecognized option`, make sure you install the latest Linux version instead of the one built in to your kernel. This can be done in Termux using `pkg install findutils`

Comment: Thanks Timothy. I figured out the solution, which I'll post shortly.

Comment: Hi Timothy, I get `unrecognized option` for `--backup==numbered` even after running `pkg install findutils` and restarting Termux. Ideas?

Comment: Yikes! It worked for me after installing findutils. I have no further ideas since I can't recreate your issue. Sorry!

Comment: I asked at the Github. Looks like it's in `coreutils` now https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1959#issuecomment-353482678

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer I managed to figure out:

```
find /SourceDir -type f -exec mv -i {} /DestinationDir ';'
```